# Как правильно организовать веб-приложение в VS Code?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, шаблонизаторы

Я сделал простенькую html страничку. Мне нужно сделать шаблонизатор на php(по сути поделить всю страницу на лейаут и отдельные блоки). Но я в vs code до этого не работал. Скачал расширение Open PHP/HTML in browser. Но как я понял оно просто открывает файлы в браузере через file:///. Можно как-то настроить так, чтобы открывался localhost?И require не работает у меня. Я неправильно указал ссылки?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Мир Обоев</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/fonts/fonts.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body> 
     <header class="overlay">
       
             <div class="title-icons">
                  <h1 class="header-title"> Мир Обоев </h1>
                  <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/178197/fabric-material.svg" alt="Обои">
                  <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/17547/paint-roller.svg" alt="Валик">
                  <img src="https://library.kissclipart.com/20180830/zfw/kissclipart-paint-bucket-drawing-easy-clipart-drawing-paint-cl-4ba76cb2a6a5fa60.png" alt="Краска">
                  <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/household-items-2/100/glue-1024.png" alt="Клей">
                  <p class="main-text">Интернет магазин<br>от эконом до премиум</p>
             </div>
            
             <div class="site-info" >
              <a class="phone" href="tel:+79289063707"> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6FV2Mqb/pngtree-phone-icon-png-image-1817554-Photo-Room-png-Photo-Room.png" alt="Обои">+7 (928) 906-37-07</a>
              <p><img src="https://i.ibb.co/D7Vkf5p/png-transparent-computer-icons-clock-angle-illustrator-time-Photo-Room-png-Photo-Room.png" alt="Обои">ежедневно 9:00 — 19:00</p> 
             </div>
       
             <div class="contact-info">
               <div class="c-info"> 
                 <a href="#" class="word">О компании</a>
                 <span class="separator"></span>
                 <a href="#" class="word">Новости</a>
                 <span class="separator"></span>
                 <a href="#" class="word">Услуги</a>
                 <span class="separator"></span>
                 <a href="#" class="word">Интересное</a>
                 <span class="separator"></span>
                 <a href="#" class="word">Контакты</a>
               </div>
              <div class="links">
               <a href=""><img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/telegram-2019-logo.svg"></a>
               <a href=""><img src="https://deskmed.ru/wp-content/files/photo-1-1536x1536.png"></a>   
               <a href=""><img src="https://i.ibb.co/r0BWc2k/xy-KKxm6-Y2k-Va-P-FPjhv3-M-transformed.png"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="search">
               <input type="search" id="site-search" placeholder="Поиск по сайту..." />
               <button></button>
              </div>
             </div>

         <div class="shop-menu" >
    <div class="shop-submenu">
         <button class="button4"><img  src="https://d3r4tb575cotg3.cloudfront.net/static/noun_1351298.png" > Поддержка</button>
 <button class="button4"><img  src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1507/PNG/512/applicationssystem_103794.png" > Настройки</button>    
    </div>
          <div>
            <img style=" width: 250px; height: 80px;" class="image" src="https://toshop.ru/pictures/action_2539.jpg" > 
          </div>
                
    <div class="shop-submenu1">
        <a  class="button1"><img  src="https://i.ibb.co/FDrPTry/Location-Larger.png"> Город</a>
        <a  class="button2"><img  src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/digital-symbols/100/ECommerce_Digital_Website_Media_Interface_Online-130-1024.png" > Вход</a>
        <button class="button3"><img  src="https://i.ibb.co/D11L2Ss/shopping-cart-computer-icons-white-png-favpng-CUXn-L8s3z-Zy-EZLunnr3-Dd-TEQX-removebg-preview.png" > Корзина</button>
    </div>
       
     </header>
    
       <div class="container">
              <section class="menu">
                      <div class="catalog">
                      <div class="catalog-header"><span>Категории</span></div>
                  <ul class="catalog-list">
                      <li class="catalog-item">
                   <label  class="catalog-link">
                            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/178197/fabric-material.svg" alt="Обои" >
                    <p class="list">Обои<p>
                         </label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                         <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                     <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Россия</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Германия</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Италия</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Нидерланды</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Франция</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Китай</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Англия</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Турция</a></li>
                     </ul>
                         </div>                 
                      </li>
                      <li class="catalog-item">
                     <label  class="catalog-link">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/t2KNtpb/650-6500238-png-file-removebg-preview.png" alt="Фотообои">
                   <p>Фотообои</p>
                         </label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                         <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                     <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Пейзажи и природа</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Города и архитектура</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Искусство и абстракция</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Детская комната</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Космос и наука</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Еда и напитки</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Интерьер и дизайн</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Праздники и события</a></li>
                     </ul>
                      </li>         
                      <li class="catalog-item">
                     <label  class="catalog-link">
                        <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/24636/parquet.svg" alt="Настенные покрытия" >
                    <p>Настенные покрытия</p>
                         </label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                         <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                     <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">3D обои</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Текстурные покрытия</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Обои с объемными узорами</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Спецэффекты на стенах</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Флоуресцентные и светящиеся обои</a></li>
                     </ul>
                      </li>         
                      <li class="catalog-item">
                     <label  class="catalog-link">
                 <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/178197/fabric-material.svg" alt="Жидкие обои">
               <p>Жидкие обои</p>
                         </label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                         <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                     <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Текстурные</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Металлические</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Цветные</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">С эффектом мрамора</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Глянцевые</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Декоративные</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">С эффектом стекла</a></li>
                     </ul>
                      </li>         
                  <li class="catalog-item">
                           <label class="catalog-link">
                            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/household-items-2/100/glue-1024.png" alt="Клей" >
                     <p>Клей</p>
                         </label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                         <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                     <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Универсальный</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Для бумажных обоев</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Для виниловых обоев</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Для текстильных обоев</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>         
                  <li class="catalog-item">
                     <label  class="catalog-link">
                    <img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_551306.png" alt="Ламинат" >
                     <p>Ламинат</p>
                 </label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                         <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                     <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Paradise</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Ritter</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Winlerk</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">WesterHof</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Egger Pro</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">GreenWald</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">EuroHome</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">AGT</a></li>
                     </ul>
 
                  </li>     
            <li class="catalog-item">
                     <label  class="catalog-link">
                            <img src="https://library.kissclipart.com/20180830/zfw/kissclipart-paint-bucket-drawing-easy-clipart-drawing-paint-cl-4ba76cb2a6a5fa60.png" alt="Краска" >
                    <p>Краска</p>
                 </label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                         <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                     <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Paradise</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Ritter</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Winlerk</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">WesterHof</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Egger Pro</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">GreenWald</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">EuroHome</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">AGT</a></li>
                     </ul>
 
                  </li> 
                  <li class="catalog-item">
                     <label  class="catalog-link">
                            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/178197/fabric-material.svg" alt="Лепной декор" > 
                    <p>Лепной декор</p>
                         </label>
                   <input type="checkbox" id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu-checkbox">
                         <div class="catalog-subcatalog">
                     <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">Перфект</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="catalog-subcatalog-link">EuroWood</a></li>
                     </ul>
 
                      </li>                     
                  </ul>
              </div>
              </section>    

             <section class="content">

               <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/xhDqN50/1879.png"  />        
                  <p class="card-text">Marburg Empire (Германия)</p>
                  <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4747</h5>
                  <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                  <h3 class="card-price">1150 Р</h3>
                  <button>Купить</button>
               </div>

               <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/F8VPmFq/1878.png" />        
                  <p class="card-text">Zambaiti Parati Canova (Италия)</p>
                  <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4772</h5>
                  <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                  <h3 class="card-price">1500 Р</h3>
                  <button>Купить</button>
               </div>

               <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-image"src="https://i.ibb.co/hKzLVHM/1880.png"/>
                  <p class="card-text">Primo Parati TESORO (Италия)</p>
                  <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 5243</h5>
                  <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                  <h3 class="card-price">1800 Р</h3>
                  <button>Купить</button>
               </div>
               
               <div class="card">
               <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/2g4c5rk/1877.png"/>
                  <p class="card-text">Erismann Erismann (Россия)</p>
                  <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4725</h5>
                  <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                  <h3 class="card-price">2400 Р</h3>
                  <button>Купить</button>
               </div> 
               
               <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/zNd0mKT/1876.png"/>
                  <p class="card-text">Zambaiti Parati Melodia (Италия)</p>
                  <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4245</h5>
                  <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                  <h3 class="card-price">999 Р</h3>
                  <button>Купить</button>
               </div> 
               
               <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/HVpqLbS/1875.png" />         
                  <p class="card-text">Zambaiti Parati Melodia (Италия)</p>
                  <h5 class="card-art">Арт. 4443</h5>
                  <h5 class="card-width">Ширина: 1.06 м</h5>
                  <h3 class="card-price">999 Р</h3>
                  <button>Купить</button>
               </div>
     
             </section>

       </div>
            <footer class="footer">
               <div class="footer-content">
                  <h4 class="footer-author">Мир Обоев © 2023. All Rights Reserved</h4>
                  <a class="email" href="mailto:makleo2002@gmail.com">Email: makleo2002@gmail.com</a>
               </div>
            </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
a:hover{
  color: #FFFF00;
}
a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
.overlay {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(95 13 238 / 0.5);
}
.overlay h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 26px;
}
.title-icons{
   margin: 2% 0 0 7%;
   width: 17%;
   height:50%;
}
.title-icons img {
   width: 15%;
}
.title-icons p{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 40% 0 0
}
.site-info{
   margin: 3% 0 0 0;
   width: 18%;
   height: 30%;
}
.site-info img{
  width: 10%;
}
.phone {
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.phone:hover{
  color: #FFFF00;
}
.contact-info{
  width: 33%;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.c-info{
  margin:3% auto;
}
.word {
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: white; /* Цвет текста */
  matgin: 100 0 0 0;
}
.separator {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.links{
width: 300px;
height: 70px;
margin: 15px 0 25px 20px;
}
.links img{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 9%;
}
.search{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.search input{
  width: 90%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.search button{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3936/3936453.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
}
.shop-menu{
   width: 20%;
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   margin: 1% 0 0 5%;
}
.shop-menu img{
  width: 35%;
  margin: 5% auto;
}
.shop-submenu{
  display: inline-flex;
}
.shop-menu button:active {
  transform: scale(0.95); /* Добавляем эффект при нажатии на кнопку */
}
.shop-submenu button{
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
}
.shop-submenu img{
  width:25px;  
  height:25px;
}
.shop-submenu1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 9% 0 0;
}
.button1{
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(95 13 238 / 0);
  border: 2px solid rgb(95 13 238 / 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center; /* Выравнивание текста по центру */
  display: flex; /* Используем flex для центрирования текста и изображения */
  justify-content: center; /* Центрирование по горизонтали */
  align-items: center; /* Центрирование по вертикали */
}
.button2{
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(95 13 238 / 0);
  border: 2px solid rgb(95 13 238 / 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center; /* Выравнивание текста по центру */
  display: flex; /* Используем flex для центрирования текста и изображения */
  justify-content: center; /* Центрирование по горизонтали */
  align-items: center; /* Центрирование по вертикали */
}
.button3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FFD700, #FFFF00);
  border: 2px solid #FFD700;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  text-align: center; /* Выравнивание текста по центру */
  display: flex; /* Используем flex для центрирования текста и изображения */
  justify-content: center; /* Центрирование по горизонтали */
  align-items: center; /* Центрирование по вертикали */
}
/* Стили для кнопок настройки и поддержки */
.button3:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FFFF00, #FFD700);
}

.button4 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #73769e, #73769e);
  border: 2px solid #73769e;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button4:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #555878, #555878);
}

.button4 img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.image{
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
}
.container {
  display: flex; /* Установите контейнеру flex-контейнером */
  background-color: #f0fbfe;
}
.menu {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 3% 5% 0 1%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #3399FF, #9933CC);
  text-align: center;
  color: white; /* Цвет текста в меню */
}
.catalog-header{
  margin: 5% 0 0 0;
}
.content {
  width: 770px;
  margin: 5% 0 0 0 ;
  font-size: 0;
  flex:1;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 25px 25px 30px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 black;
  position:relative;
}
.card button{
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ff3f46;
  border: #ff3f46;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
}
.card button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0102, #ff0102);
}
.no-right-margin {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card-price {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4.5%;
  left:5%;
}
.card-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
.card-image {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.card-width{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 5%;
}
.card-art{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17%;
  left: 5%;
}
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Центрировать содержимое по горизонтали */
  align-items: center; /* Центрировать содержимое по вертикали */
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #5f0dee;
}
.footer-content {
  text-align: center; /* Центрировать текст по центру */
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.email {
  margin-top: 10px; /* Добавить отступ между названием и почтой */
  display: block; /* Перенести почту на следующую строку */
   color: white;
  font-size: 18px; /* Уменьшить размер шрифта для почты (по желанию) */
}
.footer-author {
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.catalog-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.catalog-link img{
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
}
.catalog-subcatalog {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.catalog-subcatalog-link {
  color: white;
}
.catalog-subcatalog-link:hover {
  color: #FFD700; /* Желтый цвет текста при наведении */
}
/* Стили для отображения подменю при наведении */
.catalog-item:hover .catalog-subcatalog {
  max-height: 200px; /* Высота подменю */
}
/* Скрытие чекбоксов */
.sub-menu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.catalog-link:hover {
  color: #FFD700; /* Желтый цвет текста при наведении */
}
```

[image: структура веб-приложения]

[image: расширение]

Comment: Чтобы открыть страницу через localhost, нужно запустить какой-либо сервер и настроить его, чтоб он эту страницу отдавал. В случае с php сервер еще должен уметь дёргать CGI скрипт. Чаще всего для php используется apache.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/articles/144242/

Comment: "Чаще всего для php используется apache" Это лет 10 назад было актуально.